MS graph api not returning file property when filtering on drive items
I am developing a solution where I need to apply a filter to drive items using the Microsoft Graph API, while also requiring information from the file and sharepointIds properties. Therefore, I am using both the $filter and $select attributes in the request.
The request looks as follows:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items?$filter=folder eq null&$select=sharepointIds,name,id,file

If I execute the query without the $select parameter, I receive the file property but not the sharepointIds property. When I run the query with the parameter $select=sharepointIds,name,id, I get the SharePoint IDs but the file property is missing. If I extend the parameter to $select=sharepointIds,name,id,file to select the file Property, I get the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "badArgument"
        },
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable."
    }
}

It does not matter which filter I apply in the $filter parameter.
How can I get both the sharepointIds and file properties in a single query when using the $filter parameter?
